# How to handle Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: on using FileProvider (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

Am trying to support Nougat by getting rid of FileUriExposedException.When I use `Uri.fromFile(gettheImageFilehere())` method I successfully get the image path **file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170308_171951.jpg**
When I use

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(HomeView.this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                gettheImageFilehere());
```

I get the image path as : **/external_files/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170308_171951.jpg**

I have tried to use the implemetation provided on [android.os.FileUriExposedException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/2083526)
Here is my code in my **androidmanifest.xml**  inside  I added the provider:

```
<provider
       android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
       android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
       android:exported="false"
       android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
           android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

I then created the **provider_paths.xml** in **res/xml** folder as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

My doubts about the above:

1. In some example I found that they use the full path. i.e **Android/data/com.example.com/files**.I don't know if its the same as just having the path as a. Hopefully someone can clear that up for me.

The full error am getting is Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external_files/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170308_175833.jpg (No such file or directory)

The code snippet .java file is [here](http://pastebin.com/a2zZSrHp) to view my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try using
           `Intent iGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);`